My pyinstaller is unable to open the exe file after creating it
Exception: Unable to access file 'C:\Users\ayush\dist\Keylogger.exe': [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\ayush\dist\Keylogger.exe'enter image description here
If someone could make me understand why this is happening becoz earlier i have have made the exe file and run it and it would work properly this time only it is giving me prblm .I have made it sun with the command "python -m pyinstaller  C:\Users\ayush\OneDrive\Desktop\Keylogger\Keylogger.py --onefile --windowed " this would work fine.

Please provide a [mcve], which is code and build instructions, and what output it produces as text, not images. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].
